# Trying to copy frame of UIView ends up with negative offsets

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, interface-builder

I'm fiddling around with Interface Builder and get this frustrating offset problem:

I have created a view with some sub-views hierarchy:

```
[parent view]
    |--> (dummy backround)
      |--> (a template UIView)
```

The template is there so designers should be able to tweak the coordinates of a planned more complex view. I want to copy the coordinates into a programatically created view. This is what I do:

```
 UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:pagesBounds.frame];
 theView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
 [self.view addSubview:theView]; // self.view is the parent view from above
```

So far so good, but I see a negative offset in `theView` that can be best shown in the left-bottom corner:

[image]

My goal is that the programatically created view (the darker grey one) should position itself exactly above the template view (the white one). I have gone through the views in IB and ensured that the 'Autoresize Subviews' are off for all views (although the real view gets added to the top-most).

Obviously I'm still missing something. Suggestions?

Comment: Does the view you're copying the frame to have the same superview as the view you're copying the frame from?

Comment: D'oh! Now I feel really stupid. That was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it is offset occurs is because when you get the frame of the "template UIView", it is described in terms of the coordinates of the "dummy background". To position it properly you should do something like this:

```
UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(pagesBounds.frame, dummyBackground.frame.origin.x, dummyBackground.frame.origin.y)];
theView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:theView]; // self.view is the parent view from above
```